# Concatenating values from earlier rows with different dates in a pandas dataframe

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

An extension to my [previous question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57974133/concatenate-values-from-earlier-rows-in-a-pandas-dataframe). I have a source dataframe, which has three columns: Customer, Date and Item. I want to add a new column that contains Item History, being an array of all the Items for that Customer that are in earlier (defined by the Date) rows. *Where a customer has made multiple purchases on the same date, neither row's item should be listed in the item history for the other.*

So, given this sample data:

```
df = pd.DataFrame({'Customer':['Bert', 'Bert', 'Bert', 'Bert', 'Bert', 'Ernie', 'Ernie', 'Ernie', 'Ernie', 'Steven', 'Steven'], 'Date':['01/01/2019', '15/01/2019', '20/01/2019', '20/01/2019', '22/01/2019', '01/01/2019', '15/01/2019', '20/01/2019', '22/01/2019', '01/01/2019' ,'15/01/2019'], 'Item':['Bread', 'Cheese', 'Apples', 'Pears', 'Toothbrush', 'Toys', 'Shellfish', 'Dog', 'Yoghurt', 'Toilet', 'Dominos']})
```

```
Customer    Date    Item
Bert    01/01/2019  Bread
Bert    15/01/2019  Cheese
Bert    20/01/2019  Apples
Bert    20/01/2019  Pears
Bert    22/01/2019  Toothbrush
Ernie   01/01/2019  Toys
Ernie   15/01/2019  Shellfish
Ernie   20/01/2019  Dog
Ernie   22/01/2019  Yoghurt
Steven  01/01/2019  Toilet
Steven  15/01/2019  Dominos
```

The output I'd like to see would be:

```
Customer    Date    Item        Item History
Bert    01/01/2019  Bread       NaN
Bert    15/01/2019  Cheese      [Bread]
Bert    20/01/2019  Apples      [Bread, Cheese]
Bert    20/01/2019  Pears       [Bread, Cheese]
Bert    22/01/2019  Toothbrush  [Bread, Cheese, Apples, Pears]
Ernie   01/01/2019  Toys        NaN
Ernie   15/01/2019  Shellfish   [Toys]
Ernie   20/01/2019  Dog         [Toys, Shellfish]
Ernie   22/01/2019  Yoghurt     [Toys, Shellfish, Dog]
Steven  01/01/2019  Toilet      NaN
Steven  15/01/2019  Dominos     [Toilet]
```

Note that for Bert's purchases on 20/01/2019, neither's History column contains the other's item. For his 22/01/2019 purchase, both of the items from 20/01/2019 are included.

The answer to the previous question is a nifty bit of list comprehension, in the form:

```
df['Item History'] = [x.Item[:i].tolist() for j, x in df.groupby('Customer') 
                                          for i in range(len(x))]

df.loc[~df['Item History'].astype(bool), 'Item History']= np.nan
```

But obviously "i" in the `x.Item[:i]` needs to work out the last row where the Date was not the same as the current row. Any advice on achieving that is much appreciated.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Idea is distinguish duplicated values per groups by [`DataFrame.duplicated`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.duplicated.html) and then replace values to `NaN`s with forward filling missing values.

First values per groups are always empty strings, so not necessary replace per groups:

```
df['Item History'] = [x.Item[:i].tolist() for j, x in df.groupby('Customer') 
                                          for i in range(len(x))]

df['Item History'] = df['Item History'].mask(df.duplicated(['Customer','Date'])).ffill()

df.loc[~df['Item History'].astype(bool), 'Item History']= np.nan
print (df)
   Customer        Date        Item                    Item History
0      Bert  01/01/2019       Bread                             NaN
1      Bert  15/01/2019      Cheese                         [Bread]
2      Bert  20/01/2019      Apples                 [Bread, Cheese]
3      Bert  20/01/2019       Pears                 [Bread, Cheese]
4      Bert  22/01/2019  Toothbrush  [Bread, Cheese, Apples, Pears]
5     Ernie  01/01/2019        Toys                             NaN
6     Ernie  15/01/2019   Shellfish                          [Toys]
7     Ernie  20/01/2019         Dog               [Toys, Shellfish]
8     Ernie  22/01/2019     Yoghurt          [Toys, Shellfish, Dog]
9    Steven  01/01/2019      Toilet                             NaN
10   Steven  15/01/2019     Dominos                        [Toilet]
```

Answer (score 2):

Another way with `apply` and `np.cumsum()`:

```
#aggregates Item as list per 'Customer'& 'Date'
m=df.groupby(['Customer','Date'])['Item'].apply(lambda x: 
                               [*itertools.chain.from_iterable([x])])
#groups each Customer and cumsum the list with shift
n=m.groupby(level=0).apply(lambda x:np.cumsum(x).shift())
df.set_index(['Customer','Date']).assign(Item=n).reset_index() #assign back
```

---

```
   Customer        Date                            Item
0      Bert  01/01/2019                             NaN
1      Bert  15/01/2019                         [Bread]
2      Bert  20/01/2019                 [Bread, Cheese]
3      Bert  20/01/2019                 [Bread, Cheese]
4      Bert  22/01/2019  [Bread, Cheese, Apples, Pears]
5     Ernie  01/01/2019                             NaN
6     Ernie  15/01/2019                          [Toys]
7     Ernie  20/01/2019               [Toys, Shellfish]
8     Ernie  22/01/2019          [Toys, Shellfish, Dog]
9    Steven  01/01/2019                             NaN
10   Steven  15/01/2019                        [Toilet]
```

Answer (score 1):

A possibly simpler answer just using apply - this may be slower than other methods:

```
df['item history'] = df.apply(lambda x: 
            [i for i in list(df.loc[(df.Date<x.Date)&(df.Customer==x.Customer),'Item'])], axis=1)
```

result:

```
   Customer               ...                                  item history
0      Bert               ...                                            []
1      Bert               ...                                       [Bread]
2      Bert               ...                               [Bread, Cheese]
3      Bert               ...                               [Bread, Cheese]
4      Bert               ...                [Bread, Cheese, Apples, Pears]
5     Ernie               ...                                            []
6     Ernie               ...                                        [Toys]
7     Ernie               ...                             [Toys, Shellfish]
8     Ernie               ...                        [Toys, Shellfish, Dog]
9    Steven               ...                                            []
10   Steven               ...                                      [Toilet]
```

You may want to add `list(set())` to the result if you want list of unique items.

Comment: Thanks for the input, I particularly liked the simplicity of this method, but it was indeed slower.